# No account for team "null"

Tags: flutter

```
$ flutter ios build --release
```

It shows `Multiple valid development certificates available (your choice will be saved):`

However it doesn't show the `distribution certificate selection`, I use `--release` flag though,,,

I checked I have installed production certification correctly in local machine.

Is there any clue to solve??

```
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
    note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build descriptionerror: No account for team "null". Add a new account in
    the Accounts preference pane or verify that your accounts have valid credentials. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')error: No
    profiles for 'jp.****.****' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching
    'jp.****.****'. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@whitebear, I am assuming you're trying to release your iOS app? Have you tried manually configuring distribution certificate in Xcode? I usually do this,

- Open `Runner.xcworkspace` in Xcode
- Configure distribution certificate in Xcode
- Run `flutter build ios` in Android Studio project terminal
- Then archive in Xcode to publish

Answer (score 0):

To address the 'No Account for team null' issue.
Make sure you have the DEVELOPMENT_TEAM build setting set properly.

I think this is because when you are sign your app with a a provisioning profile associated with a development team Xcode expects your DEVELOPMENT_TEAM building setting to match.

I typically let XCode Automatically Manage Signing when I'm building/running my app in development and thought that doing so would automatically set the DEVELOPMENT_TEAM build setting, but that doesn't seem to be the case.